# Clustering points with maximum number of points using QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, clustering, spatial-cluster

I have a dataset of 488 GPS points which I would like to break up into small clusters. The maximum number of points per cluster should be 3.

I have tried the K-means clustering tool in Vector Analysis, however this does not give me the option to set a maximum amount of points, only a minimum. Similarly I have tried the ConcaveHull plugin, but I don't think a maximum number of points can be set with this either.

I am using QGIS.

Comment: If you wish to ask about ArcMap or R then please do that in a separate question and for the latter include a code attempt.

Comment: Any other rules? Minimum number of points? Maximum distance? As it stands your requirements could be satisfied by 488 clusters of 1 :)

Answer (score 0):

I recently had a similar challenge. When searching, I found the python script from the link at https://spatialthoughts.com/2021/01/31/equal-sized-kmeans-qgis/.
See if it works for you.

Comment: Please expand your answer by including a code section and explaining why this solution solves the issue. Just posting a link isn't really an answer, it's more of a comment. Please [see](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer#:~:text=Write%20to%20the%20best%20of,your%20answer%20to%20improve%20it.) here on how to give a good answer.